# python fabric run(command) the command is escaped ' change to \'?

Tags: python, fabric

For my command

```
command = '''/home/andy/Documents/python_project/ebaysdk/bin/python3 -u /home/andy/Documents/python_project/ebaysdk/myprogram/run_collectiondata_a.py "[('CCIYU', 'EBAY-MOTOR', 1371602535, 20954)]"'''
```

I use Python Fabric to run it

```
con.run('''%s''' % (command))
```

but have an error,the ' escape to \'

```
Command: '/home/andy/Documents/python_project/ebaysdk/bin/python3 -u /home/andy/Documents/python_project/ebaysdk/myprogram/run_collectiondata_a.py "[(\'CCIYU\', \'EBAY-MOTOR\', 1371602535, 20954)]"'
```

in which character `'` is escaped to `\'`

How can i prohibit such escaping？

Comment: I take it that your command ends by an " ? Maybr not, as it's also missing in the error message !

Comment: @B. Go  i have change. but the the error is being

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from using the 2 kinds of quotes inside the string, and especially from having a string defined by ' (3 not needed) containing some '.
Try with (not checked, as I don't have the con command set up):

```
command = "/home/andy/Documents/python_project/ebaysdk/bin/python3 -u /home/andy/Documents/python_project/ebaysdk/myprogram/run_collectiondata_a.py \"[('CCIYU', 'EBAY-MOTOR', 1371602535, 20954)]\""
con.run(command)
```

command is already a string and should be accepted as is by con. using outer " and inner \" should protect the innermost '